# Vertical scrolling with horizontal scrolling lists render errors

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

Having difficulty with a Flutter layout which includes an appBar() at the top, a BottomNavigationWidget() at the bottom and content in the middle that is vertically scrollable but has horizontal list views as well. The problem is I continue to run into viewport errors that vary in their specificity, no matter what I attempt to correct or modify related to the SingleChildScrollView() that sits beneath the appBar().

Each horizontal row is built from a future that returns a list of images that comes from ContentList. Since I need to be able to make multiple requests for different images in each horizontal row, I call buildCategory("title", 0), buildCategory("new title", 1),  buildCategory("another title", 2)and so on, as to pull down different images and display them with a unique title as illustrated in the image below.

[image: Mockup of how layout should look and work]

I've constructed that layout like so below however you can't scroll vertically, only horizontally on each included  buildCategory method despite being wrapped in a SingleChildScrollView and contained within a Column. If I deviate from this I get layout exceptions thrown.

I've included the full code I'm working with to better share/show.

```
Future<List<ContentDetails>> getContent(http.Client client, int filter) async {
  
  var response = await client.get(
      Uri.parse(baseUrl + '/imageendpoint/$filter'));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    compute(parseContentDetails, response.body);
  } 
}

List<ContentDetails> parseContentDetails(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  return parsed
      .map<ContentDetails>((json) => ContentDetails.fromJson(json))
      .toList();
}
```

```
class ContentList extends StatefulWidget {
  const ContentList({Key? key, required this.photos}) : super(key: key);

  final List<ContentDetails> photos;

  @override
  State<ContentList> createState() => _ContentListState();
}

class _ContentListState extends State<ContentList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: widget.photos.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          children: <Widget>[
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Container(
                height: 150.0,
                width: 150.0,
                child: Container(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                      image: widget.photos[index].image,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0),
                      child: Text(widget.photos[index].name)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```
Widget appBar() {
  return AppBar(
            title: const Text("Welcome"),
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent
          );
}
```

```
Widget horizontalContent(int filter) {
  return FutureBuilder<List<ItemDetails>>(
    future: getContent(http.Client(), filter),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return const Center(
          child: Text('Error.'),
        );
      } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return ContentList(photos: snapshot.data!);
      } else {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
    },
  );
}
```

```
Widget buildCategory(String title, int category) {
  return Flexible(
    child: ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child:
              Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
            TitleWidget(
                titleText: title,
                titleAlign: TextAlign.right),
            SmallButton(
                buttonText: "Details",
                onPressed: () => {},
                )
          ]),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 200, child: horizontalContent(filter))
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationWidget(),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  colors: [
                    Color.fromRGBO(0, 85, 85, 85),
                    Color.fromRGBO(0, 66, 66, 66),
                    Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0),
                  ],
                  stops: [0.0, 0.3],
                ),
              ),
              child:
                  Image.asset("images/background.png", fit: BoxFit.cover)),
          appBar(),
         SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
            buildCategory("title", 0),
            buildCategory("title", 1),
            buildCategory("title", 2),
            buildCategory("title", 3),
            buildCategory("title", 4),
            buildCategory("title", 5),
            buildCategory("title", 6),
          ])),
           
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[BottomNavigationWidget()],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your `Scaffold` use `appBar` and

```dart
  AppBar appBar() {
    return AppBar(
        title: const Text("Welcome"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent);
  }
```

```dart
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: appBar(),
// bottomNavigationBar: ,
  body: ListView.builder( // top level listView
    itemCount: 44,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
        height: 200, // must provide based on your preference
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Text("header $index"),
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: 33,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                  width: 200,
                  height: 100,
                  child: Text("hrIem"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I will need to refactor this to work with my future so I can build multiple listsview.builders.

Comment: yes, sometime you need to provide ScrollController if issue rise, But it is better to use CustomScrollView for cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Scaffold(
    extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
    appBar: appBar(),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationWidget(),
    body: ListView(
     children: [
       SizedBox(
          height: 300, // give your height
          SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Column(
           mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
            buildCategory("title", 0),
            buildCategory("title", 1),
            buildCategory("title", 2),
            buildCategory("title", 3),
            buildCategory("title", 4),
            buildCategory("title", 5),
            buildCategory("title", 6),
          ]
        )
       ),
      ),


    SizedBox(
          height: 300, // give your height
          SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Column(
           mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
            buildCategory("title", 0),
            buildCategory("title", 1),
            buildCategory("title", 2),
            buildCategory("title", 3),
            buildCategory("title", 4),
            buildCategory("title", 5),
            buildCategory("title", 6),
          ]
        )
       ),
      )
    ]
  ),
)
```